# Can I manually assign a value to a cell?

Tags: human-resource-machine

Specifically, I want to assign the number 14 to a cell at the start of my program so I can create a list beginning at cell 14. I have my reasons.

I already have a cell with a 0 in it and know it's possible to use the bump command 14 times. However, this is time and memory inefficient so I'd rather not. Is there a better way to set a cell to 14?

Comment: I don't know... starting a list at 14 sounds inefficient to me...

Comment: @Powerlord I had my reasons. I can't remember what they were but I had them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use an addition chain to build the number 14, rather than just bumping a 0 14 times, but no, there's no other way to assign a specific arbitrary number to a cell.

```
copyfrom 0
copyto 1
bump+ 1
bump+ 1
bump+ 1
add 1
copyto 1
bump+ 1
add 1
copyto 1
```

Now you have 14, both in your hand and in cell 1. If you don't already have a 0, you can build one by subtracting the first input from itself.